# conditional formatting excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

Is there a way to highlight a cell (possibly with conditional formatting) if one of the cells to the left of it has data, but it is empty?

for instance,

```
     A     B     C     D     
   ________________________
1 |     |     |     |  x  |
2 |     |  x  |     |     |
3 |  x  |     |     |     |
4 |     |     |     |     |
5 |     |     |     |     |
```

In the example, cells C2, D2, B3, C3, D3 would be highlighted because they are empty but there is a value in a cell to the left of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the range you want to apply the conditional formatting rule to and go to `Conditional Formatting` on the Home ribbon, then `New Rule...`. From there choose `Use a formula to determine which cells to format` and enter the formula below.

```
=AND(COUNTA($A1:A1)=1,A1="")
```

Here `A1` is the top-left cell of the selected range. Adjust the formula to fit your needs.

Next set the desired format/highlighting and click `OK`.

Answer (score 0):

To highlight the cells in col B which appear next to a blank cell in col A:

- Put the cursor on B1 and select Conditional Formatting -> New rule.
- Select the last option in the list of rule types, "Use a formula to
  determine..."
- In the field that says "Format values where this
  formula is true:" enter "**=IF(ISBLANK(A1),TRUE,FALSE)**" (see screenshot)
- Click the format button to select exactly how you want the highlighted cells to appear
- Click OK, then OK again to exit the Rules Manager.
- Right click on B2 and select the Format painter (see screenshot) then drag down the column to apply that rule to the rest of the column as needed.

[image: The rule settings]

[image: Select Format Painter]

[image: Final result]